# Karabiner-Elements Ctrl + Left Click to Left Click doesn't work

Tags: macos, karabiner

Using Mac OS Catalina and on Mac OS a Ctrl + Left click = Right click. This is very annoying however I found a post that showed how Karabiner-Elements could fix this. I imported the rule and it is enabled, however it still doesn't work and Ctrl + left Click still = Right Click. Any help to get this working would be appreciated.

Update: opened event viewer and found that left clicks and right click don't show up, is this supposed to happen or do I need to enable Karabiner reading mouse in settings somehow?

Comment: Install older version

Comment: but Karabiner-Elements 13.1.0 is for Catalina 10.15.6 or later and I'm on Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: I have BigSur and Catalina before and version 13 is not working on my machine

Comment: so would downloading an old version even work? is it worth giving it a try?

Comment: Yeah in my case that was helping

Comment: ok, Ill give it a try

Comment: can you import the Ctrl + Left click to Left click please and tell me if it works for you

Comment: The older versions do not work, just tried

Comment: I can see there's something called Mouse keys in keys panel, have you tried it ? On my machine it's empty

Comment: got it fixed, because i'm using a usb mouse it didn't automatically enable as a device so i just had to enable it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think using an older version of Karabiner-Elements is a bad ideal. If you're using a mouse, then you need to turn on the corresponding device to make it continue to work. *Karabiner-Elements Preferences -> Devices -> Basic configuration* and enable the mouse, which is useful for me when use IDEA for source code tracking