# Is there no Ctrl+drag selected text to copy it available in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to drag and drop a selected text by pressing and holding a modifier key in Visual Studio Code? Usually, this is Ctrl+Drag. But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ctrl + Drag works for me on Windows. What's your platform?

Comment: I am on macOS currently, when using Ctrl+Click a right-click is performed. Is there another modifier?

Comment: Do you have `Editor: Drag and Drop` enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I think the problem with macOS is, that system-wide Ctrl+Click means right-click. I discovered and installed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674991/karabiner-elements-ctrl-left-click-to-left-click-doesnt-work). This seems to map correctly now after enabling my mouse in Devices - Basic configuration. Tested on desktop. No pop-up menu anymore. But in VS Code no drag & drop yet.

Comment: Try using the Troublershooter for keybindings. Press `F1` then type troubleshoot and select the option that says **"Toggle Keyboard shortcuts Troubleshooting"** then open the `Output Panel` (which is not the same as the terminal). Make sure you select the output named `Log (Window)`. Then see what is happening when you press CTRL.

Comment: To give you a reference, on Linux (Typical Debian Distro) It shows `[2022-02-25 22:48:51.464] [renderer5] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control` -- **THEN** -- `Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')`

Comment: My guess is that on a mac, VSCode will register some other event that what I posted above as the output I see in my Debian OS. If this is the case, then you know its a system issue, and you have to figure out how to get the event that VSCode is looking for to register when you **A** _Either hold down the control key_, or **B** _Figure out a hack to get the same event I posted above on some other key_.

Comment: Just to touch on a similar topic. In JetBrains IDEs (Specifically IntelliJ & CLion), You can configure keybindings for keys that are held in the lock position _(lock pos = held down)_. Hopefully VSCode will support a similar feature in the future. I know that the lock position keybindings in intelliJ is a feature that is highly praised by mac users.

Comment: This is what I get: [2022-02-27 08:53:38.417] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-02-27 08:53:38.418] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-02-27 08:53:38.418] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-02-27 08:53:38.561] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Storing single modifier for possible chord ctrl.

Comment: [2022-02-27 08:53:38.861] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Clearing single modifier due to 300ms elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the default configuration, there's no need for CTRL key. Just selecting the text and dragging it in place (using left mouse click) does the job.

Version: 1.64.2

Comment: Sometimes the obvious things aren't the things you try first. I've tried all modifier keys, but not without them. It works without pressing a modifier key. Perfect.

Comment: this doesn't copy, just moves the text. (cut & paste, not copy & paste)

Answer (score 0):

Try command (⌘) + click. I believe Apple's "CTRL" key is the "⌘" key, and its "ALT" key is "CTRL" (that's why you right click was happening; ALT + click = right click).